# Excel custom number format: Is there a way to show the number in basis points (bps)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I would like to show a cell in basis points, so that if the numeric value is 0.01, it renders as a string "1 bps" in the cell; 1.00 would show "100 bps"

Is there a way to do this through custom formatting in Excel?

Comment: You can customize a currency format to have "bps" at the end, but you'll have to multiply your result by 1000.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Is there anyway to have it show by 1/10000th? similar to the "M" and "K" formats for million and thousands, respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It is a bit tricky / obscure ...

1. Create a custom format like this: 0" bps"%%
   Each % sign multiplies the value by 100 so two of them gets you from a raw value to bps.
   You can leave out the text (" bps") or add decimals (0.0 vs just 0) ... your preference.
   This format for a value of 0.01 shows 100 bps%% ... which is not ideal with the weird %% at end.

Now here's the trick

2. Go back into the custom format ... move your cursor between the second " and the first % hold down Alt and type the numbers 010 on number pad. (that creates a line break between the " and %
   Hit OK
3. The cell will still look the same (with the %% at end) but then format the cell as Wrap Text and presto!!!  the %% falls to the next line and is hidden
   Now the cell with 0.01 shows "100 bps"